# Entropy of a matrix?

Tags: matrices, entropy

I'm a programmer and I'm trying to create a program where I need to calculate how random or disordered a matrix is. I read this answer here: [Entropy of matrix](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/221832/entropy-of-matrix) but it did not really help me.

What I'm trying to do is that if I have a kind of binary matrix (of only 0s and 1s), I want to calculate how disordered (or ordered) it is. I'm looking to quantify the word disorder of a matrix. I know it is possible by calculating entropy of the matrix, but I'm not sure at all how to implement such algorithm.

For example, a matrix consisting of only 0s and 1s should return entropy as 0. Matrix like:

```
1 0 1
0 1 0
1 0 1
0 1 0
```

should also have low entropy. 
Matrix like:

```
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 0
1 0 1
1 1 1
1 1 0
```

should have slightly higher entropy than previous. How do I quantify all these arrangements? (Order of matrix is not fixed).

Comment: Are you considering the rows as elements (through which you can define the entropy) or the scalar entries separately?

Comment: @user3658307 I'm more kind of looking for a pattern. Roughly speaking, the larger and/or more repeating the pattern is, lower should the entropy be.

Comment: What are asking about seems like some kind of pattern recognition problem that may be hard to even define. As a simple idea, what if you treated the rows as realizations of a vector random variable and computed the discrete entropy?

Comment: @user3658307 I'm not sure what that means. Strictly speaking it's not really my subject (I'm a programmer). I had an idea of a game which I laid down and found that I need to somehow quantify the entropy of such a matrix system.